# Chainsaw chain replacement

Tags: chainsaw, chain

I need to replace my chainsaw chain. The specs of the original chain are .058” gauge .325”pitch drive links 76 Semi-chisel chain. The closest to the specs I can find locally, differ, the drive links are 78 and it’s FULL chisel (I don’t know what chisel means w/chainsaw chains) Can I use this chain?

Comment: What chainsaw do you have?

Comment: It’s a  Salem Master Pro. I lost my Stihl in divorce to my ex-husband 

Comment: You may need to get a new chain online after websearching the model number of the chainsaw.

Comment: The gauge, the pitch, and the number of drive links are important for the fit.  The type of tooth(chisel, semi chisel) is important for the type of cutting you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into a  store that sells these chainsaws and just ask them what chain it requires.  You dont have to buy it from there.  I would buy it there, myself.

If you havent replaced a chain before, it can get a bit fiddly.  I would get them to install it too.

Answer (score 1):

The forestry stores or chainsaw service centers can make you custom chains.
They have large reels of chain and are more than happy to make you a chain loop with any number of drive links you desire.

From what I gather, Stihl doesn't have any chainsaws with 1.5mm (.058”) gauge. The Oregon "21" chain should match, except the chisel style (?). Husqvarna should also have a chain with matching pitch and gauge in their productline.

Gauge, pitch and number of drive links must match. Tooth style (chisel vs. semi chisel) match is optional (see below).

It is also an option to let them equip you with an different blade. That would give you the option of changing the number of drive links. That could be a possibility to give you a matching chain with semi-chisel. To what extend that is possible or legal should be asked to them.

Chisel vs. semi chisel means how aggresive the teeths are. Semi-chisel often gets sold to customers who don't have much experience, as they are less prone to kickback. They are also recommended for weaker chainsaws. Full chisel has an more aggressive cut, offers higher cutting speed, but should be reserved for experienced users as it is more prone to kickback.